# Comparing pandas data frame in groups based on condition in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of grouped data in panada frame 1 like
like -
print(df_data)

```
group   id   Person item    amount
group_1 6339    ABC IceCream    16.87
group_1 6339    ABC Candy       71.31
group_1 6339    ABC Pen         9.83
group_1 6422    XYZ Candy       55.46
group_1 6422    XYZ IceCream    10.97
group_1 6422    XYZ Pen         3.53
group_1 6541    LMN Candy       6.16
group_1 6541    LMN IceCream    4.48
group_1 6541    LMN Pen         1.34
group_1 7185    DEF Candy       56.44
group_1 7185    DEF IceCream    8.23
group_1 7185    DEF Pen         5.71
group_2 6422    XYZ Pen         3.53
group_2 6541    LMN Candy       6.16
group_2 6541    LMN IceCream    4.48
```

another data frame contains rule for grouped data like
print(df_rule)

```
Item      min   max
Candy     100   140
IceCream   20    50
Pen        15    40
```

So as per the rule the sum of Candy in a group cannot be more than 140 and cannot be less than 100

So when we check group_1 then we see it has

```
Candy      189.37
IceCream    40.55
Pen         20.41
```

So group_1 passes and group_2 fails.
I want a similar logic that I can apply on df_data based on df_rule and finally, for those groups that pass this criterion I can store them in a data frame and discard those fails

Comment: how does group1 pass when 189.37 > 140?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your expected output but you could use a custom function per group to identify the non matching values:

```
s = df_rule.set_index('Item')
def between(g):
    ref = s.loc[g.name[1]]
    return ref['min'] <= g.sum() <= ref['max']

df_data.groupby(['group', 'item'])['amount'].apply(between)
```

output:

```
group    item    
group_1  Candy       False
         IceCream     True
         Pen          True
group_2  Candy       False
         IceCream    False
         Pen         False
Name: amount, dtype: bool
```

Assuming a group passes if **all** values are within the bounds, use:

```
df.groupby(['group', 'item'])['amount'].apply(between).groupby(level=0).all()
```

output:

```
group
group_1    False
group_2    False
Name: amount, dtype: bool
```

But here both fail.

If **any** value is fine (in this case use `any`), then group1 passes